# (fancyvrb) Error when finishing environment followed by text

Tags: errors, verbatim, fancyvrb

I'm trying to compare he different packages that support `verbatim` content and I noticed that there is a small, but, big difference in behavior when closing the environment followed by text (not a new line). With this example file:

```
\documentclass{article}%
%\usepackage{verbatim}\newenvironment{myverbatim}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
\usepackage{newvbtm}\newverbatim{mynewvbtm}{}{}{}{}
\usepackage{listings}\lstnewenvironment{mylistings}{\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}}{}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{myfancyvrb}{Verbatim}{}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill

This text is found just before opening the verbatim (default, no package) environment 
\begin{verbatim}
  default verbatim environment
\end{verbatim}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment

\noindent\hrulefill

This text is found just before opening the verbatim (with listings package) environment 
\begin{mylistings}
  verbatim with listings package
\end{mylistings}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment

\noindent\hrulefill

This text is found just before opening the verbatim environment 
\begin{mynewvbtm}
  verbatim with newvbtm package
\end{mynewvbtm}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment

\noindent\hrulefill

%This text is found just before opening the verbatim (with verbatim package) environment 
%\begin{myverbatim}
% LaTeX Warning: Characters dropped after `\end{verbatim}' on input line
%\end{myverbatim}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment
%\noindent\hrulefill

%This text is found just before opening the verbatim (with myfancyvrb package) environment 
%\begin{myfancyvrb}
%! FancyVerb Error:
%  Extraneous input `This text is found just after closing verbatim environment\
%end{}' between \end{myfancyvrb} and line end
%.
%\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
%\space \space #1
%}
%\end{myfancyvrb}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment
\end{document}
```

The text after `\end{verbatim}` is placed on the following line.
If we use the {verbatim} package we get the message:

```
LaTeX Warning: Characters dropped after `\end{verbatim}' on input line
```

The text "*This text is found...*" is not displayed on the output, which is correct and appears in the package documentation, but with `fancyvrb` you only get one error:

```
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `This text is found just after closing verbatim environment\
end{}' between \end{myfancyvrb} and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}
```

Is there any way to **skip** this error?, without having to place the text on the following line, either by placing the text on a new line or by sending a warning message (I don't know which one is the most indicated).

I don't know if it's an error in the package or if it's due to the implementation of this one. I've written an email to Herbert (I think he also belongs to this community), but, he hasn't given me an answer.

Greetings

Comment: An error seems to be the correct thing here, it is a syntax error in the file (which is quite hard to recover from)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I understand it, the truth is that I don't need to put text as such, rather a comment `\end{myfancyvrb} %`...but the error spoils everything...and you don't do the same with the other packages...

Comment: but the `%` isn't a comment character in that context and by the time the `\end{myfancyvrb}` is detected it is too late to make it so. The _whole line_ has already been read with verbatim settings

Comment: Ok, I understand that I can't detect it, but I could ignore the rest of the line if it starts with a comment ... and not show the error message. I think that placing a %comment at the end of an environment is valid.

Comment: No placing a `%comment` after a verbatim environment (from this package or the verbatim package) is explicitly _not valid_ it is a syntax error in the document.

Comment: Really, this compiles without error. `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}\begin{verbatim}verbatim environment\end{verbatim}% 
\end{document}` ... only Warning

Comment: yes it is warning you that the document is in error. Either way whether you get a warning or an error, you should fix the document not to have text in that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from

```
\def\FV@BadEndError{%
  \expandafter\@temptokena\expandafter{\@tempb}%
  \FV@Error
      {Extraneous input `\the\@temptokena' between
        \string\end{\FV@EnvironName} and line end}%
      {This input will be discarded. Type <return> to continue.}}
```

so you could make that a warning by putting

```
\makeatletter
\def\FV@BadEndError{%
  \@warning
      {Extraneous input  between
        \string\end{\FV@EnvironName} and line end}%
      \let\next\FV@EndScanning}
%
```

in the preamble, but an error seems more reasonable than a warning here, as it is a syntax error in the document.

Note that I had to change the example as you can not have the string `\end{myfancyverb}` within a `myfancyverb` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}%
%\usepackage{verbatim}\newenvironment{myverbatim}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
\usepackage{newvbtm}\newverbatim{mynewvbtm}{}{}{}{}
\usepackage{listings}\lstnewenvironment{mylistings}{\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}}{}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\makeatletter
\def\FV@BadEndError{%
  \@warning
      {Extraneous input  between
        \string\end{\FV@EnvironName} and line end}%
      \let\next\FV@EndScanning}
%\makeatother

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{myfancyvrb}{Verbatim}{}
\begin{document}


\noindent\hrulefill

This text is found just before opening the verbatim (default, no package) environment 
\begin{verbatim}
  default verbatim environment
\end{verbatim}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment

\noindent\hrulefill

This text is found just before opening the verbatim (with listings package) environment 
\begin{mylistings}
  verbatim with listings package
\end{mylistings}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment

\noindent\hrulefill

This text is found just before opening the verbatim environment 
\begin{mynewvbtm}
  verbatim with newvbtm package
\end{mynewvbtm}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment

\noindent\hrulefill

%This text is found just before opening the verbatim (with verbatim package) environment 
%\begin{myverbatim}
% LaTeX Warning: Characters dropped after `\end{verbatim}' on input line
%\end{myverbatim}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment
%\noindent\hrulefill

This text is found just before opening the verbatim (with myfancyvrb package) environment 
\begin{myfancyvrb}
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `This text is found just after closing verbatim environment\
end{}' between \end{myfanc--yvrb} and line end
.
p\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}
\end{myfancyvrb}This text is found just after closing verbatim environment
\end{document}
```

Comment: actually I decided I do not understand your question, I get no error from the test file you provided??? @PabloGonzálezL

Comment: I'll undelete in a bit

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL added working example and undeleted the post

Comment: Thank you very much Master David, those are the precise lines I was looking for... Still...I still think it's "almost a bug" in the `fancyvrb` package.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I would say it is definitely a bug in the document, if I was maintaining the package I would certainly make it issue an error here,

Comment: Ok, but, `verbatim` (no packets) supports this type of entry as valid, as well as `listings`...maybe it's something that can be added to `fvextra`.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL yes but a standard verbatim can't be nested in another newenvironment, and has no customisation of the formatting, doing either of those things more or less forces you to read the environment line-by-line and that more or less forces weird handling of text after the close environment on the same line. It is not done for no reason or without looking at possibilities for avoiding the issue.

Comment: I am clear, you can add your comment to the answer you have given me ... now I understand the reason for the error and the limitations of the solution you proposed ... but I do not intend to nest the environment:)